# How to create normal (direction) widget?

Tags: python, interface

I'm looking a way of creating widget like `normal` node has in Cycles.

[image]

I have examined names of all method in [UILayout](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UILayout.html) but it looks neither of them are related with `Normal` widget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it is not a separate widget as I thought but argument for float vector property (`subtype='DIRECTION'`). In general it can be done in next way:

```
    vector: bpy.props.FloatVectorProperty(default=(0.0, 0.0, 1.0), subtype='DIRECTION')

    def draw_buttons(self, context, layout):
        layout.prop(self, 'vector')
```

Test script.

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import FloatVectorProperty

context = bpy.context

bpy.types.Scene.normal = FloatVectorProperty(subtype='DIRECTION')

def draw(self, context):
    scene = context.scene
    self.layout.prop(scene, "normal")

bpy.types.SCENE_PT_scene.prepend(draw)

context.window_manager.popover(draw)
```